# Spark Shell "Failed to Initialize Compiler" Error on a mac

Tags: macos, scala, apache-spark, installation

I just installed spark on my new machine and get the following error after installing Java, Scala and Apache-spark using homebrew. The install process is given below:

```
$ brew cask install java
$ brew install scala
$ brew install apache-spark
```

Once installed, when I try to run a basic example using `spark-shell`, i get the following error. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
$ spark-shell
 Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).

Failed to initialize compiler: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
** Note that as of 2.8 scala does not assume use of the java classpath.
** For the old behavior pass -usejavacp to scala, or if using a Settings
** object programmatically, settings.usejavacp.value = true.

Failed to initialize compiler: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
** Note that as of 2.8 scala does not assume use of the java classpath.
** For the old behavior pass -usejavacp to scala, or if using a Settings
** object programmatically, settings.usejavacp.value = true.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.exitingPhase(SymbolTable.scala:256)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.x$20$lzycompute(IMain.scala:896)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.x$20(IMain.scala:895)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.headerPreamble$lzycompute(IMain.scala:895)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.headerPreamble(IMain.scala:895)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$Wrapper.preamble(IMain.scala:918)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$CodeAssembler$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(IMain.scala:1337)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$CodeAssembler$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(IMain.scala:1336)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.package$.stringFromWriter(package.scala:64)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$CodeAssembler$class.apply(IMain.scala:1336)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$Wrapper.apply(IMain.scala:908)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.compile$lzycompute(IMain.scala:1002)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.compile(IMain.scala:997)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.compile(IMain.scala:579)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:567)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:98)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:920)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:755)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)`
```

Comment: Can you uninstall `scala` package and start over? It's not needed for Spark as it comes with necessary libraries/jars already. The error looks like a version mismatch between Scala versions (and Spark has just revealed it).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Spark is incompatible with Java 9, which is the version `brew cask install java` will install if it is up to date. If you did install Java 9, what you need to do is install Java 8 instead:

```
brew cask uninstall java
brew tap caskroom/versions
brew cask search java
brew cask install java8
```

Comment: Sir, you deserve a medal :)

Comment: what else can I try when even this does not work? :(

Answer (score 4):

As ZackK wrote spark is incompatible with Java9, so you can check the versions of java you have in your machine and choose a compatible version, assuming you have one.

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Which in my case returned:

There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

- 0/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      auto mode
- *1/opt/java/jdk-9.0.4/bin/java                     1         manual mode

The asterisk in front of 1 denotes the active version. Choosing 0 changed it to a compatible version.

```
$ java -version
```

which returned:
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"

After the change spark-shell worked.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem. But when I checked my laptop java version, it was 9.
I just changed to java 8 and found every thing working fine.

Just check this solution. Hope it will work if you getting exact same error as start of this thread.

Answer (score 0):

win10:
You have to convert to jdk8:
Set up JAVA_HOME = jdk8;
Discard from path the C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
(it always show the jdk9)

Comment: How will this help?

Answer (score 0):

Problem: Spark incompatible with current Java version

Here is another solution that use [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/)

Install sdkman

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

Then you should close and open another Terminal.

After that, install Java 8

```
sdk install java 8.0.181-zulu
```

Now, test if it work. Go to your spark/bin then run

```
./spark-shell
```

You should not see that error again.

Answer (score 0):

updating the alternatives is required for not only java
`$ sudo update-alternatives --config java`
 but also javac, javap etc. 
`$ sudo update-alternatives --config javac`

So its better to remove above 8 java versions, and then install the java 8.